# javascript array push problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have the following javascript code:

```
var objectArray = [];
var allInputObjects = [];
var allSelectObjects = [];
var allTextAreaObjects = [];

//following returns 3 objects
allInputObjects = document.getElementById("divPage0").getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

//following returns 1 object
allSelectObjects = document.getElementById("divPage1").getElementsByTagName("SELECT");

//following returns 0 objects
allTextAreaObjects = document.getElementById("divPage2").getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA");

//and following statement does not work
objectArray = allInputObjects.concat(allSelectObjects);
```

And my problem is that the last line is throwing an error.

I tried the above code in Firefox and it says `allInputObjects.concat` is not a function.

Any clues, I believe the script is not treating allInputObjects as an Array!

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, which is similar to an `Array` except that it does not support all those prototype functions.

To seamlessly convert such an array-like object into an Array, use:

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(somenodelist, 0);
```

`arr` will almost be identical, except that it now has the `Array` prototype functions supported, like `concat`.

What the function actually does is returning a partial `Array` containing the elements of `somenodelist`, to be precise everything from index 0 and after. Obviously, this are just all elements, therefore this is a trick to convert array-like objects into real `Array`s.

Comment: +1 since this contains an actual solution to the problem (converting the `NodeList` back to an array).

Comment: You can't expect host objects to behave when passed to native ECMAScript functions. In this case, IE < 9 (at least) will fail.

Comment: @RobG: Really? I believe jQuery also utilizes this function in it `.toArray` function.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think that `allSelectObjects` *is* an array?

It is initially assigned to an empty array, sure.  But then it's overwritten by the `getElementsByTagName` call on line 6(ish).  Variables in Javascript are not strongly typed, so the initial assignment does not force later assignments to also be arrays.

I suspect you'll have some type of `NodeList` or similar, rather than an array, in the variable when you invoke the final line.  (That's what's [returned by the method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) in Firefox, at least.)

Answer (score 3):

As Andezej has pointed out, you're not dealing with an array here, you're dealing with a kind of node list.

Here's one way you can create an array to work with based on the result of `getElementsByTagName`

```
        var tags = obj.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var j=0;j<tags.length;j++) {
            resultArray.push(tags[j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another funny way to convert your `NodeList` to an array:

```
var tags = obj.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    tags2Arr = ( 
           function toArr(i){
             return i ? toArr(i-1).concat(tags[i]) : [tags[0]];
           }(tags.length-1) 
    );
```

Now if you add a method to the `Array.prototype`:

```
Array.prototype.clone = function() {
    var arr = this;
    return (function clone(i){
     return i ? clone(i-1).concat(arr[i]) : [arr[0]];
    })(this.length-1);
};
```

You can convert a `NodeList` to an array, using this oneliner:

```
Array.prototype.clone.call(obj.getElementsByTagName('input'));
```